# date_select and time_select are not taking the start_year and end_year and order parameters in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time

i m using the rails  `date_select` and `time_select` with the following options.
but for `date_select` `start_year` and  `end_year` and  `order` options are not working. and for `time_select`  `ampm:true` option is not working.

```
    <%= label_tag :date,"Date" %>
    <%= date_select :date, { start_year: Date.today.year - 1, :end_year => Date.today.year, order: [:day, :month, :year] }  %>

    <%= label_tag :check_in,"Check In Time" %>
    <%= time_select :check_in, {ampm: true} , {}  %>

    <%= label_tag :check_out,"Check Out Time" %>
    <%= time_select :check_out, {ampm: true}, {}   %>
```

and how to apply class attribute. iam giving like this but styling is not working.

```
    <%= time_select :check_out, {ampm: true} ,{:class => 'form-control' }  %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on Rails [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) the `date_select` is defined as

> date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})

you are placing `options` as the second parameter when it should be the third one.

solution 1:

```
<%= date_select :date, nil, { start_year: Date.today.year - 1, :end_year => Date.today.year, order: [:day, :month, :year] }  %>
```

You have the same problem for the [time_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select):

> time_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})

solution 2:

```
 <%= time_select :check_out, nil, {ampm: true} ,{:class => 'form-control' }  %>
```

Comment: and how to apply class attribute. iam giving like this but styling is not working.   <%= time_select :check_out, {ampm: true} ,{:class => 'form-control' }  %>

Comment: the same problem as the `date_select`... answer updated for you.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are in the wrong order. It should be:

```
<%= label_tag :date,"Date" %>
<%= date_select :date, {}, { start_year: Date.today.year - 1, :end_year => Date.today.year, order: [:day, :month, :year] }  %>

<%= label_tag :check_in,"Check In Time" %>
<%= time_select :check_in, {}, {ampm: true} %>

<%= label_tag :check_out,"Check Out Time" %>
<%= time_select :check_out, {}, {ampm: true}   %>
```

See also: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select